# Separate sonar project for a gradle subproject

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarscanner

I have a project with the following structure in gradle (root, childA and childB are modules each with their own build.gradle)

- `root`

  - `childA`
  - `childB`

I have a sonar analysis setup such that it analyzes the whole project into a project `root-analysis` on sonarqube.

With the `childA` submodule growing bigger, I wish to transfer its analysis into a separate sonarqube project `a-analysis` and remove it from the `root-analysis`.
Is there a way to do so?

What I've tried

- Calling `:root:childA:sonarqube` doesn't work as it says task sonarqube not found in gradle.
- Adding `sonar.projectKey` property(with value `a-analysis`) to the child sonarqube settings block hoping it would send its analysis to another sonarqube project. Doesn't work.
- trying to register the sonar plugin in the child gives an error, the plugin has already been registered.

I'm currently using `sonar-gradle plugin 2.6.2`, and it'd be great if I didn't have to update that.

THanks!